# Failing to switch between view controllers using swift

Tags: switch-statement, viewcontroller

I have previously written this function and it was working fine. I started working on the project again after a week's break and the same code is not working. Am I missing something here? Basically if a button is pushed, checkCredentials will run. Everything in the "else" section is working completely fine, but the "if user != nil" section isn't working:

```
    func checkCredentials (){
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameLoginTxt.text!, password: passwordLoginTxt.text!){
        (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil{


            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchViewController") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion:nil)
            NSLog("it was successfull dude")

        }else{

            let title = "Warning!"
            let message = "You have entered the wrong username or password.\n Please try again!"
            let okButton = "Ok"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okButton, style:  UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:  nil)
            alert.addAction(okayButton)

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    }

}
```